# Doxygen-like documentation for python code from a C++ project

Tags: python, c++, documentation, swig, documentation-generation

I've been working on this C++ library (using C++17) for quite some time now. Most of my users want it for Python because they do not know C++, so I had to write an interface of the library for Python. For this, I chose to use SWIG.

Needless to say that while developing I wrote the library's documentation. I wrote it using Doxygen's comments (the version of Doxygen that I currently use is `1.9.1`), for example

```
/**
 * @brief Summary of a function's behaviour.
 *
 * A few more details...
 * @param param1 Meaning of parameter 1
 * @param param2 Meaning of parameter 2
 * @pre Precondition 1
 * @pre Precondition 2
 * @post Postcondition 1
 * @post Postcondition 2
 * @returns What this function returns is...
 */
```

I really can't complain about the generation of the `html` files by Doxygen: the C++ documentation generation is all right and meets all my needs.

Now I would like to have the documentation for the Python interface because the users who wanted the library for Python do not know any C++ (or so I've been told). With this I mean: I wish to offer my users (if possible) the possibility of navigating the library's documentation as in the C++ `html`, but for Python, i.e. -- as explained below in more detail -- without `std::vector< >`, without `const`, without the `&`, and all C++'s language features that do not apply to Python (as a side note: I can stop Doxygen from documenting blocks of code inbetween `#ifndef` but that will not help get rid of all that many `std::vector` and such). Moreover, instead of `namspace1::namspace2::function`, something like `namespace1.namespace2.function` (and the users will be told that the strings `namespace1` and `namespace2` are Python modules (and that is the way the Python interface is organized); I've made a little progress by simply replacing the appropriate strings inside the `html` files. For example, any `std::vector&lt; int &gt;` that I find I can replace it with, say, `list_of_ints` and that's good enough for the time being.

But this is not automatic enough, so I have tried the following:

- Generate `xml` files with Doxygen (`GENERATE_XML = YES`), parse these with [doxy2swig.py](https://documentation.help/Sphinx/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathjax) (it takes the `xml` files and generates a `.i` file with the documentation from C++ into a list of items beginning with `%feature("docstring")` for SWIG to use), and then added a `%include "output_of_doxy2swig.i"` in every `.i` that I want to be documented. I must say, this one is nice: the description of what the function does and the parameters it takes and their description are added into a Python' docstring. But, besides not having been able to use `sphinx`, `pydoc`, or `pydoctor` to produce an output (`html` files) without the word `Undocumented` left and right, the `@pre` and `@post` are lost (or ignored) and modules' documentation is missing.
- Using SWIG's `-doxygen` command line option the results are a bit better. Just like before, the description of the function and of the parameters are added, but no `@pre` nor `@post` nor module documentation. Another good thing is that SWIG writes the strings in a format that `sphinx` can use to produce nice `html` files.

There are problems, however, in both of the options above: the types written as the output types of functions, i.e., the `"int"` in

```py
def function() -> "int":
    # ....
```

are sometimes written with C++ types. I mean, even after interfacing a `std::vector<int>` using `%template(list_int) std::vector<int>;` the return type is

```py
def function() -> "std::vector< int >":
    # ....
```

The users of the Python interface are, most likely, going to be Python users with no knowledge whatsoever of C++, and the `"std::vector< int >"` are going to get more than of these users confused.

My questions for you are these:

- Is there any option to get SWIG to:

  - add module documentation?
  - add the `@pre` and `@post` to the docstrings?
  - generate the functions like this?

  ```
  def function() -> "list_int":
      # ....
  ```

  where `list_int` is the interface of `std::vector<int>` that I wrote in a `.i` file: `%template(list_int) std::vector<int>;`.

Affirmative answers to these above are very much appreciated. Regardless of the answers, I'd like to ask two more questions.

- Is there any tool out there which, given the set of `html` files generated by Doxygen from the C++ sources, replaces the C++ types (like `std::vector<>`, `std::pair<,>`, `std::array<,>`) with something of my choice? For example: from `std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>>` to `list_of_pairs_of_int_and_string` (I'll deal with the naming later). This would be ideal (even if such a tool does not deal with templates) because all the formulas `\f$...\f$` would also be rendered in the `html` files for Python ([I know sphinx admits mahjax](https://documentation.help/Sphinx/math.html#module-sphinx.ext.mathjax) but I still haven't managed to get it to work). A tool like this seems to be extremely convenient since, basically, there is less work to do, but I don't have high hopes for one to exist.
- Is there some tutorial/manual/ that explains step by step, and with at least one minimal working example (which I haven't been able to find), how to automatically generate python documentation from C++ sources interfaced  to python with swig without C++ types (like STL containers)? Or maybe there exists an existing project that has had to face the same issues? For example, CGAL has Python bindings for the C++ library but I've got a strange feeling that it isn't wrapped with SWIG (but, please, tell me if I'm wrong).

Thank you all for your time and patience. I really hope to get some affirmative answers, but I'm ready to hear bad news (specially about the last two).

Comment: What do you mean with "Now I would like to have the documentation for python."? Which version of doxygen ? What is wrong when you feed the C++ and the python code to doxygen and generate HTML output.

Comment: Hello @albert . Thank you for your questions. I've tried to answer your first two questions by editing the post. But I don't understand your last question _What is wrong when you feed the C++ and the python code to doxygen and generate HTML output._ 

Do you mean I can feed Doxygen some C++ code (call it 'A'), the result of SWIG's python code (a wrapper for the C++ code 'A'), and obtain `html`? Where can I read more about this and what does it do?

Comment: I don't know SWIG but I assume it outputs some python files based on the input C++ code on a special directory, can't you feed these python files into doxygen?

Comment: I use Doxygen to generate xml and `doxy2swig.py` with option `-c -a` to generate a `documentation.i`. I get documentation for modules, say classes as well function. If you want to change the return types, you could do a search and replace using the types you have defined in your interface file as a post build step to generating the `documentation,i`. The replacement is easily done using `sed`. Also, you can change the LaTeX command to run twice to get references correct.

Comment: @JensMunk What version of `doxy2swig.py` do you have? The one I have does not admit options `-c` nor `-a`. Where can I get it?

Comment: @albert I must admit I never though about feeding python files to doxygen (I didn't know you could do that). I've looked at [this](https://www.woolseyworkshop.com/2020/06/25/documenting-python-programs-with-doxygen/) guide and I can see I'm going to have some problems as SWIG does not generate the docstrings doxygen needs to generate the `html` properly.

Comment: @llualpu The version I am using is with modification from Michael Thon. It accepts options, -c, -a, -o and some formatting options. @albert doxygen is set to generate xml and `doxy2swig.py` generates SWIG code. It is pretty neat. https://github.com/m7thon/doxy2swig/blob/master/doxy2swig.py